# Copy, Insert copied cells and shift down

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a macro which copy from range `A1:A20` (only cells that contain text because in between there are empty cells), then paste to another column `B` and remove duplicates. The third column `D` is designed to "store" the content, so I'd like to insert copied cells and shift cells down.
Searching the forums I managed to put together macros that I found, however it's not working. If you guys can help me to modify the code or propose other solution - it will be much appreciated.

```
Sub ValuesOnly()
Dim R As Range, V As Variant, A As Variant, i As Long, ct As Long
Set R = Sheets("Booking Sheet").Range("A1:A20")
V = R.Value
ReDim A(1 To UBound(V, 1))
For i = 1 To UBound(V, 1)
    If V(i, 1) <> "" Then
        ct = ct + 1
        A(ct) = V(i, 1)
    End If
Next i
Sheets("Booking Sheet").Range("B1:B20").Resize(ct, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(A)
Sheets("Booking Sheet").Range("B1:B20").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes

End Sub

Sub InsertCellsShiftDown()
Dim bookingWS As Worksheet
Dim copyRng As Range

Set bookingWS = Sheets("Booking Sheet")
Set copyRng = bookingWS.Range("B1", bookingWS.Range("B1").End(xlDown))

bookingWS.Range("D1:D" & copyRng.Rows.Count + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
copyRng.Copy bookingWS.Range("D1")

End Sub
```

Macros are working separately, I can't put them together.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever consider using the `=UNIQUE()` worksheet function? This removes duplicates without the need of a VBA macro, as you can see in following screenshot (the formulae are mentioned on row 6):

[image]

Used formulae:

- `=SORT(UNIQUE(A1:A20))` : remove all duplicates and sort the results
- `=IF(NOT((B1=0)),B1,"")` : The `UNIQUE()` function produces a "zero" value. This formula gets rid of this.